# Are C++ compilers allowed to replace construct + moveconstruct with just a construct?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, move-constructor, copy-elision

Are C++ compilers allowed to replace:

```
const auto myType = MyType(1, 2, 3);
```

with:

```
const MyType myType(1, 2, 3);
```

ie, emit the assignment, or is there anything which prevents this?

*Note:
The reason I ask is that I prefer the first version.*

Comment: Yes, thats what the compilers should do instead of creating a temporary and then calling a copy or move constructor.

Comment: The first syntax requires a non-explicit, non-deleted and accessible move-/copy-constructor (though it may change in the future).

Comment: There's no assignment, this is initialization.   And assuming the first one compiles, then yes the compiler can eliminate the temporary. This is called *copy elision*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
object when certain criteria are met, it's called [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are permitted to omit
>   the copy- and move-constructors of class objects even if copy/move
>   constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects.

And for your code,

> If a function returns a class type by value, and the return
>   statement's expression is the name of a non-volatile object with
>   automatic storage duration, which isn't the function parameter, or a
>   catch clause parameter, and which has the same type (ignoring
>   top-level cv-qualification) as the return type of the function, then
>   copy/move is omitted. When that local object is constructed, it is
>   constructed directly in the storage where the function's return value
>   would otherwise be moved or copied to. This variant of copy elision is
>   known as NRVO, "named return value optimization".

Note that the copy/move ctor still need to be accessible.

> Even when copy elision takes place and the copy-/move-constructor is not called, it must be present and accessible (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the program is ill-formed.